# How does the Abstract Interpreter work?

Tags: c, interpreter, abstract

I am trying to build an abstract interpreter for C. Probably not for the whole grammar but for just a subset of it. I have previously asked on what language to use. Before I proceed any further, I would like to know how this abstract interpretation works ?

I have gone through the Wiki links and the lecture note links. I have understood the rationale and the theory behind it. I have my analysis worked out. The part I am totally not able to understand is how to interpret the code.  That is, I had the initial code. I now have it preprocessed. I have also performed some normalization to the code which is required by my analysis.  Now, how do I execute the code line-by-line and extract data out it as I keep executing it? (Please tell me if this is impossible. Or there is some way to properly execute the program which will achieve my objective). I am looking at collecting the information like the memory address of the dynamically allocated space, the return addresses of the function call.

I was suggested CIL earlier, CIL is mostly a transformation tool, transforming the code to some normalized form taking care of many anomalies but I was not able to get any information pertaining to my problem.

My question is how to extract the information line by line and which language is preferable ? Imperative languages or functional languages ? I have been Googling quite a few days for information regarding this, but of no use. Any links are also highly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT : I still have some doubts. I got the part where we try to build an virtual environment. Let me explain what I am trying to do, so that it will help the discussion. I am basically trying to do pointer analysis which mainly concentrates on pointer arithmetic. Now suppose I have a integer pointer and I do an pointer arithmetic then I cannot be sure if the pointer is still pointing to a valid data.

From what you are saying, I understand we need to allocate the spaces for the variables but what about the values. if I have something like below

`int a=10;

int *p = &a;

p = p+4;`

Here the values of a and the constant '4' is known. What if I get value from user or file. In such a case I need to execute the actual program. At the same time , I need to capture the data like the address. below,

`int *p =(int *) malloc (sizeof(int));

*p= 15;

cout<<*p;

p = p+ino//some user input value;

cout<<*p;`

So basically the code has to be executed but later part of the solution sounded more like parsing the C file. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: When you say "abstract interpretation," do you mean the program analysis technique in which you try to build up a model of what the program can do, or a means of executing the C code without compiling it down to machine code?  In the former case, what analysis are you trying to perform?  In the latter case, can you elaborate on what's tripping you up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are really talking about abstract interpretation rather than merely interpreting C...

Abstract interpretation relies on two things - an abstract domain, a finite height lattice and an abstract semantics whereby the applying the semantics of a line to the value in the domain from the line before must produce a new value in the domain which is the same height or higher.

i.e. If your domain is the powerset of `{1,2,3,4}` and the input is `{1,2,3}` the only valid outputs are `{1,2,3}` or `{1,2,3,4}` (assuming usual set ordering)

You then proceed by performing fixed-point recursion on each line and storing the output of the semantics with the line, and the semantics at the end of each function with the function definition. How you choose the domain and interpret the set you end up with depends enormously on the analysis you are trying to do, but that is the outline as I understand it...

I must say i am *not* an expert with this, but some of my research colleagues have talked to me about it in the past, and this is the understanding i have come out with...

Also, you can just as easily run the analysis backwards - starting at the end of the function and moving forward, and this will be more appropriate for some kinds of analysis...

Comment: +1 This is a great description of abstract interpretation.  I hope that this is what the OP was referring to!

Comment: You have cleared my doubt as well. From the explanation, I think I am rather trying to interpret the code rather than Abstract interpret. From the problem requirement and previously question's answers, I thought this was abstract interpretation.

Comment: The lattice to use does not need to be of finite height (one of the first examples is the analysis of interval ranges for a small programming language without overflows, and the lattice of integer intervals is definitely not of finite height). Semantic functions are required to be **monotonic** (x<y => f(x)<f(y)), which is not the same thing as always returning an output larger than the input.

Comment: If you want to perform a smart constant propagation, then it's a form of an abstract interpretation.

Comment: @pascal true, but for an abstract interpretation to be guaranteed to terminate for any input the lattice does have to be finite height (as otherwise a monotonic function could keep increasing indefinitely and the fixed point recursion would never terminate), also I was trying to explain monotonicity in plain english with my statement was, given the domain and the co-domain are the same, and that fixed point recursion is used, `f(x)<=f(f(x))`... is this not accurate?

Comment: @tobyodavies Abstract interpretation terminates with non-finite height lattices thanks to the introduction of a widening operator (the words "convergence accelerator" are often used to describe widening operators). And there is a quantity that only increases during propagation until a fixpoint is reached, but it's not the output of semantic function `f` wrt its input, it's `u(n+1) = u(n) ∪ f(u(n))` (merging new values with all previous values at each iteration)

Comment: @Pascal, i see, more reading required on my part :D or you know, time for me to actually do something useful then write a paper on this... but even then i suspect reading might be involved ;)

Comment: @tobyodavies Hey, I was coincidentally writing a blog post on a specific problem in the abstract interpretation of C programs. Skip to the end of the post, there is a sequence of abstract states that show widening in action: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/01/27/On-memcpy-1

Answer (score 2):

CIL is capable of doing an [SSA-transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form). Program in SSA form is surprisingly easy to [reason about](http://www.jantar.org/papers/chakravarty03perspective.pdf) and to partially evaluate - you just have to substitute named values, ignoring or *merging* values coming from the *phi*-nodes. So, in order to turn CIL into a proper abstract interpreter you only have to add a couple of transforms after the SSA (which is already there). Alternatively, you can do this sort of transforms on top of LLVM IR produced by Clang.

Answer (score 1):

From the way you're posing your problem, it seems like what you're talking about is *interpretation*, not *abstract interpretation*.  Interpretation just means taking the C code and running it yourself, in your case to extract some information out of what happens at runtime.  Abstract interpretation refers to a static analysis procedure in which you try to make sense of what the program is capable of doing, possibly for optimization purposes or possibly to try to prove correctness or the absence of bugs.  Of course, I could be totally wrong about this, in which case you can disregard this answer.

If you are trying to write an interpreter, then you'll probably need to set up a virtual execution environment in which the program will run.  That is, you'll likely want to set up a giant array of bytes to serve as the program's memory, and will need to maintain your own stack pointer and heap allocator.  You can then execute the program by going line by line and modifying the state of this environment based on the particular line of code you're executing.  For example, executing a statement like

```
int a;
```

would work by increasing the stack pointer by four bytes, while running something like

```
a = 137;
```

would look up what part of the global memory array is referenced by `a` and then overwriting the bytes with the four-byte value for `137`.  From this point, tracking what happens during execution should be relatively straightforward - before your interpreter executes any particular statement or evaluates an expression, you can log any relevant details.

Note that this is not going to be easy.  You're going to have to manually allocate and clear stack frames, maintain a program counter, etc.  However, it sounds like a lot of fun, and I wish you the best of luck with it!

Comment: replied with an edit to the question due to the formatting problem.